# make a image slider that swaps images automatically

Tags: css, slider

I want to make a slider that swaps images automatically and also on the hover of the below links like in flipkart.com.

reference site:  [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com)

Comment: you have a try this???

Comment: [jQuery Image Slider plugins](http://codegeekz.com/jquery-image-slider-plugins/) you should find one that meets your needs.

Comment: no, not yet I am searching the web but didn't find any useful that meets my requirements.

Comment: So I take it your search consisted of the first Google result and only scanned the first paragraph. I say this because there are sliders out there that can do this. You might have to set up some configuration settings as it most likely won't be a `copy 'n paste` job. Dig a little deeper and you will find it.

Comment: @hungerstar - I searched a lot on web, I just need a slider with hover effect that I can customize to my need.

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg  I went through your link but didn't find any for me.

Comment: Trust me bro, they're out there. Keep digging.

Comment: @hungerstar can you suggest me few links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cycle2

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2

And use the goto command on the buttons to move to specific slides.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C.S.S. question. This is a JavaScript question. Go here and follow the instructions.

http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-JavaScript-Image-Rollover

A good resource is the jQuery website or use Google or Bing search engine. The input string should be JavaScript image hover or jQuery image hover.